# java.util.Iterator to Scala list?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

I have the following code:

```
private lazy val keys: List[String] = obj.getKeys().asScala.toList
```

`obj.getKeys` returns a `java.util.Iterator<java.lang.String>`

Calling `asScala`, via `JavaConverers` (which is imported) according to the docs..

```
java.util.Iterator <==> scala.collection.Iterator
```

`scala.collection.Iterator` defines

```
def toList: List[A]
```

So based on this I believed this should work, however here is the compilation error:

```
[scalac]  <file>.scala:11: error: type mismatch;
[scalac]  found   : List[?0] where type ?0
[scalac]  required: List[String]
[scalac]  private lazy val keys : List[String] = obj.getKeys().asScala.toList
[scalac]  one error found
```

I understand the type parameter or the java Iterator is a Java String, and that I am trying to create a list of Scala strings, but (perhaps naively) thought that there would be an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would work if obj.getKeys() was a `java.util.Iterator<String>`. I suppose it is not.

If `obj.getKeys()` is just `java.util.Iterator` in raw form, not `java.util.Iterator<String>`, not even `java.util.Iterator<?>`, this is something scala tend to dislikes, but anyway, there is no way scala will type your expression as `List[String]` if it has no guarantee `obj.getKeys()` contains String.

If you know your iterator is on Strings, but the type does not say so, you may cast :

```
obj.getKeys().asInstanceOf[java.util.Iterator[String]]
```

(then go on with `.asScala.toList`)

Note that, just as in java and because of type erasure, that cast will not be checked (you will get a warning). If you want to check immediately that you have Strings, you may rather do

```
obj.getKeys().map(_.asInstanceOf[String])
```

which will check the type of each element while you iterate to build the list

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! seems like you and Matthew Farwell  agree for the most part. I did what you suggest, obj.getKeys().asInstanceOf[java.util.Iterator[String]].asScala.toList and that seems to work, and I did not get a compilation warning.

Answer (score 27):

You don't need to call asScala, it is an implicit conversion:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val javaList = new java.util.LinkedList[String]() // as an example

val scalaList = javaList.iterator.toList
```

If you really don't have the type parameter of the iterator, just cast it to the correct type:

```
javaList.iterator.asInstanceOf[java.util.Iterator[String]].toList
```

EDIT: Some people prefer not to use the implicit conversions in JavaConversions, but use the asScala/asJava decorators in JavaConverters to make the conversions more explicit.

Comment: You are right, there is no type parameter for the Iterator that is being returned from the getKeys() method. Very astute observation, thank you. Though it appears I do need the asScala in there, in that case. Perhaps there is something else I am missing.

Comment: The implicit conversion is on `JavaConversions`, but not on `JavaConverters`. That uses `asScala`. Many people, myself included, prefer to make this conversion explicit to avoid subtle bugs.

Comment: @Daniel I guess making stuff explicit is a good idea, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

I dislike the other answers. Hell, I dislike anything that suggests using `asInstanceOf` unless there's no alternative. In this case, there is. If you do this:

```
private lazy val keys : List[String] = obj.getKeys().asScala.collect { 
    case s: String => s 
}.toList
```

You turn the `Iterator[_]` into a `Iterator[String]` safely and efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Note that starting `Scala 2.13`, package [`scala.jdk.CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html) replaces deprecated packages `scala.collection.JavaConverters/JavaConversions` when it comes to implicit conversions between Java and Scala collections:

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

// val javaIterator: java.util.Iterator[String] = java.util.Arrays.asList("a", "b").iterator
javaIterator.asScala
// Iterator[String] = <iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of scala 2.12.8 one could use

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

asScalaIterator(java.util.Iterator variable).toSeq
```