# Deal with Java NIO Iterator in Scala with Try

Tags: scala

I recently learned how to use Scala's native `Try` type to handle errors. One good thing with `Try` is that I'm able to use for-comprehension and silently ignore the error.

However, this becomes a slight problem with Java's NIO package (which I really want to use).

```
val p = Paths.get("Some File Path")
for {
  stream <- Try(Files.newDirectoryStream(p))
  file:Path <- stream.iterator()
} yield file.getFileName
```

This would have been perfect. I intend to get all file names from a directory, and using a `DirectoryStream[Path]` is the best way because it scales really well. The NIO page says `DirectoryStream` has an `iterator()` method that returns an iterator. For Java's for loop, it's enough and can be used like this:

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir)) {
    for (Path file: stream) {
        System.out.println(file.getFileName());
    }
}
```

However, Scala does not accept this. I was greeted with the error:

```
[error] /.../DAL.scala:42: value filter is not a member of java.util.Iterator[java.nio.file.Path]
[error] file:Path <- stream.iterator
```

I try to use `JavaConverters`, and it shows it handles Java `Iterator` type: `scala.collection.Iterator <=> java.util.Iterator`, but when I try to call it in this way: `stream.iterator().asScala`, the method is not reachable.

What should I do? How do I write nice Scala code while still using NIO package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't actually quite get while in this for comprehension `filter` is being invoked, but note that  `stream.iterator()` returns a `Iterator[Path]`, not a `Path`, even though my IDE thinks it does, probably because he thinks he can apply `map` to it, but in truth this are methods which are not defined on `java.util.Iterator[java.nio.file.Path]` as the compiler confirms:

```
scala>   for {
 |     stream <- Try(Files.newDirectoryStream(p))
 |     file <- stream.iterator()
 |   } yield file
<console>:13: error: value map is not a member of java.util.Iterator[java.nio.file.Path]
              file <- stream.iterator()
```

This for comprehension translates to:

```
Try(Files.newDirectoryStream(p)).flatMap(stream => stream.iterator().map(...))
```

Where the second `map` is not defined. One solution could be found in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589561/java-util-iterator-to-scala-list), but I can't tell you how to use iterator in for comprehension here since in java iterator cannot be mapped on and I'm not sure you can convert it into the comprehension.

Edit:

I managed to find out more about the problem, I tried this for comprehension:

```
for {
  stream <- Try(Files.newDirectoryStream(p))
  file <- stream.iterator().toIterator
} yield file
```

This doesn't compile because:

```
found   : Iterator[java.nio.file.Path]
required: scala.util.Try[?]
       file <- stream.iterator().toIterator
```

It translates to:

```
Try(Files.newDirectoryStream(p)).flatMap(stream => stream.iterator().map(...))
```

But `flatMap` actually expects a `Try` back, in fact this works:

```
Try(Files.newDirectoryStream(p)).flatMap(stream => Try(stream.iterator().map(...)))
                                                    ^
```

What I came up with:

```
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
import util.Try
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

Try(Files.newDirectoryStream(p))
  .map(stream => 
    stream
    .iterator()
    .toIterator
    .toList
    .map(path => path.getFileName.toString)
).getOrElse(List())
```

Which returns a `List[String]`, unfortunately this is far from being as pretty as your for comprehension, maybe somebody else has a better idea.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, it looks quite fantastic. The transformation however takes time, and especially when the stream is quite huge. The original reason for Java Stream is used in NIO is to scale...but nonetheless, great great answer!

Comment: Emm, unfortunately it seems like I don't even have `toIterator` method. How did you get it???

Comment: You need to `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._`.

Comment: Yeah..I did import that one, but it didn't work. That's weird. But Thank you for helping out! In the pursuit of efficiency I wrote a slightly different function :)

Answer (score 0):

I really like what Ende Neu wrote and it's hard to work with NIO in Scala. I want to preserve the efficiency brought from Java's Stream, so I decide to write this function instead. It still uses `Try` and I only need to deal with `Success` and `Failure` cases :)

It's not as smooth as I'd hope, and without Java 7's great `try-with-resource` feature, I have to close the stream by myself (which is terrible...), but this works out.

```
  def readFileNames(filePath: String):Option[List[Path]] = {
    val p = Paths.get(filePath)
    val stream: Try[DirectoryStream[Path]] = Try(Files.newDirectoryStream(p))

    val listOfFiles = List[Path]()
    stream match {
      case Success(st) =>
        val iterator = st.iterator()
        while (iterator.hasNext) {
          listOfFiles :+ iterator.next()
        }
      case Failure(ex) => println(s"The file path is incorrect: ${ex.getMessage}")
    }
    stream.map(ds => ds.close())
    if(listOfFiles.isEmpty) None else Some(listOfFiles)
  }
```